# Why are there changes in location when printing inserted points?

Tags: qgis

Añadí una capa de texto delimitado por comas y luego agregue una imagen satelital de google earth. Realizo un diseño de impresión y al imprimir cambia la ubicación de los puntos en varios metros. Cual es la solucion?

**(Edit)** Google Translation:

I added a layer of comma delimited text then added a satellite image from Google Earth. I do a print design and during printing the locations of the points change by several meters.  What is the solution?

Comment: Welcome! I would recommend posting in English to increase the chances of someone posting a solution.  Sorry for the hack translation.